# How to send request using Yii framework

Tags: request, yii

Hi how can i send request to controller/ action in Yii
similar to kohana's

```
Request::factory('controller/action')
    ->post(
        array(
            'login' => 'abc',
            'password' => 'def'
        )
    )
    ->execute();
```

I have read Yii doc but havent found word about it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you only want to redirect the page (or current action) to some other controller's action with certain post variables?

Answer (score 0):

Yii is not a [hierarchical MVC](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2000/jw-0721-hmvc.html) framework with nested views, if that is what you are trying to do. The best you can do is use nested Widgets (which can have Views).

If you are just doing a redirect, that's easy:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller/action','param1'=>'abc','param2'=>'def'));
```

But it is a "true" redirect with only GET parameters, it does not support sending POST variables.

If you are just using this for internal request routing logic, you'll have to come up with another strategy. Say you want to call the same action from two different controllers: I would recommend either creating a base Controller class with the shared actions so your other controllers can inherit them, or use Yii's modular CAction class to attach actions to controllers.

(Sorry for no links, the Yii site is down for maintenance right now.)